# Unable to read data from table in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a website built in C# in Microsoft Visual Studio.

I have a `Customer`, a `Products`, an `Orders` and an `OrdersItem` table. My site sells products, had a shopping cart and a checkout page.

The customer logs into the site using her/her username and password and selects the product they want to buy. This then add the product to the shopping cart and once the customer clicks on Checkout, it opens the following page

See .aspx markup below

```
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="BodyContent" runat="server">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="form-group alert alert-info">
               <asp:label runat="server" ID="lblCheckOut">Please enter your Details to purchase your Beer below:</asp:label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <asp:Label ID="lblName" Text="Your name: *" AssociatedControlID="txtName" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                <asp:textbox name="txtName" id="txtName" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Your name" required="required" runat="server"></asp:textbox>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <asp:Label ID="lblEmail" Text="Your email: *" AssociatedControlID="txtEmail" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                <asp:textbox name="txtEmail" id="txtEmail" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Your email" required="required" TextMode="Email" runat="server"></asp:textbox>                    
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <asp:Label ID="lblPhone" Text="Your phone: *" AssociatedControlID="txtPhone" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                <asp:textbox name="txtPhone" id="txtPhone" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Phone" required="required" runat="server"></asp:textbox>                     
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <asp:Label ID="lblAddress1" Text="Your address: *" AssociatedControlID="txtAddress1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                <asp:textbox name="txtAddress1" id="txtAddress1" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Your address" TextMode="MultiLine" required="required" runat="server"></asp:textbox>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <asp:Label ID="lblAddress2" Text="Your Town:" AssociatedControlID="txtAddress2" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                <asp:textbox name="txtAddress2" id="txtAddress2" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Town" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server"></asp:textbox>   
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <asp:Label ID="lblAddress3" Text="Your County: *" AssociatedControlID="txtAddress3" runat="server"></asp:Label><br/>
                <asp:textbox name="txtAddress3" id="txtAddress3" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Your County" required="required" runat="server"></asp:textbox>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <asp:Label ID="lblCountry" Text="Your Country: *" AssociatedControlID="txtCountry" runat="server"></asp:Label><br/>
                <asp:textbox name="txtCountry" id="txtCountry" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Country" required="required" runat="server"></asp:textbox>   
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <asp:Label ID="lblTotalCost" Text="Amount to be Paid:" AssociatedControlID="ddlCreditCardType" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
                <asp:textbox name="txtTotalCost" id="txtTotalCost" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="" runat="server"></asp:textbox>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <asp:Label ID="lblCardType" Text="Card type *" AssociatedControlID="ddlCreditCardType" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                <asp:dropdownlist id="ddlCreditCardType"  tabindex="2" class="form-control" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem value="friendship">VISA</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem value="employment">MasterCard</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem value="other">Other</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:dropdownlist>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                  <asp:Label ID="lblCardNumber" Text="Credit card number *" AssociatedControlID="txtCardNumber" runat="server"></asp:Label><br/>
                  <asp:textbox name="txtCardNumber" id="txtCardNumber" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Your card number" required="required" runat="server"></asp:textbox>   
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                         <asp:button runat="server" text="Check out" id="btnCheckOut" OnClick="btnCheckOut_Click" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-11">
                        <a href="/Backend/Default.aspx" class="btn btn-default pull-right">Continue Shopping</a>
                    </div>
                </div>    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

The `.aspx.cs` code behind this is below. The aspx code is ok as working as expected. What I am trying to do is get the aspx.cx code to populate the form with the customer's details when they click on Checkout. In the code below under `ShowCustomerDetails`, I want it to populate Name, Email and Phone details.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace CA4.Shop
{
public partial class CheckOut : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string q = Request.QueryString["id"];
        int id = 0;
        int.TryParse(q, out id);

        if (Session["username"] == null)
            Response.Redirect("../CustomerLogin.aspx");
        else
        {
            ShowCustomerDetails(id);
        }

        double CartTotalCost = 0;

        if (Session["BeerCart"] == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/Shop");
        }
        else
        {
            CartTotalCost = GetCartTotalCost();
            txtTotalCost.Text = string.Format("{0:C}", CartTotalCost);
        }
    }

    private void ShowCustomerDetails(int id)
    {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AppConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

        string getCustomerDetails = "SELECT Name, Email, Phone FROM Customers WHERE CustomerId = @id";

        //get email based on id
        SqlCommand getCustomerCommand = new SqlCommand(getCustomerDetails, connection);
        getCustomerCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
        connection.Open();

        SqlDataReader reader = getCustomerCommand.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            txtName.Text = reader["Name"].ToString();
            txtEmail.Text = reader["Email"].ToString();
            txtPhone.Text = reader["Phone"].ToString();
        }

        reader.Close();
        connection.Close();
    }

    protected void btnCheckOut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Name = txtName.Text;
        string Email = txtEmail.Text;
        string Phone = txtPhone.Text;
        string Address1 = txtAddress1.Text;
        string Address2 = txtAddress2.Text;
        string Address3 = txtAddress3.Text;
        string Country = txtCountry.Text;

        //for this example we wont store the card details
        int CustomerId = 0;

        CustomerId = AddCustomerDetails(Name, Email, Phone, Address1, Address2, Address3, Country);
        PlaceOrderForCustomer(CustomerId);
        Session["BeerCart"] = null;
        Response.Redirect("~/Shop/Thanks.aspx");
    }

    private double GetCartTotalCost()
    {
        double Price = 0;
        double ProductTotal = 0;
        double CartTotal = 0;
        Dictionary<int, int> cart = (Dictionary<int, int>)Session["BeerCart"];

        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AppConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        foreach (var item in cart)
        {
            string query = "SELECT [BeerId], [Price] FROM [Products] WHERE [BeerId] = @id";
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", item.Key);
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Price = double.Parse(reader["Price"].ToString());
                ProductTotal = Price * item.Value;
                CartTotal += ProductTotal;
            }
            connection.Close();
        }

        return CartTotal;
    }

    private int AddCustomerDetails(string Name, string Email, string Phone, string Address1, string Address2, string Address3, string Country)
    {
        int CustomerId = 0;
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AppConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        string sqlStatement = "Select Name, Email, Phone, Address1, Address2, Address3, Country) Values (@Name,@Email,@Phone,@Address1,@Address2,@Address3,@Country) FROM Customers Where [CustomerId] = @id ;SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, connection);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Name);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", Email);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", Phone);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address1", Address1);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address2", Address2);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address3", Address3);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country", Country);
        connection.Open();

        CustomerId = int.Parse(command.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
        connection.Close();

        return CustomerId;
    }

    private void PlaceOrderForCustomer(int CustomerId)
    {
        int BeerId = 0;
        int OrderId = CreateOrder(CustomerId);
        string Brand = string.Empty;
        string Name = string.Empty;
        double Price = 0;
        Dictionary<int, int> cart = (Dictionary<int, int>)Session["BeerCart"];

        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AppConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

        foreach (var item in cart)
        {
            string query = "SELECT [BeerId], [Brand], [Name], [Price] FROM [Products] WHERE [BeerId] = @id";
            connection.Open();

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", item.Key);

            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                BeerId = int.Parse(reader["BeerId"].ToString());
                Brand = reader["Brand"].ToString();
                Name = reader["Name"].ToString();
                Price = double.Parse(reader["Price"].ToString());
                AddItemToOrder(OrderId, BeerId, Brand, Name, Price, item.Value);
            }

            connection.Close();
        }
    }

    private int CreateOrder(int CustomerId)
    {
        int OrderId = 0;

        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AppConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        string sqlStatement = "INSERT INTO [Orders] (CustomerId, OrderDate) Values (@CustomerId,@OrderDate);SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();";

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, connection);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerId", CustomerId);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderDate", DateTime.Now);

        connection.Open();
        OrderId = int.Parse(command.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
        connection.Close();

        return OrderId;
    }

    private void AddItemToOrder(int OrderId, int BeerId, string Brand, string Name, double Price, int Quantity)
    {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AppConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        string sqlStatement = "INSERT INTO OrderItem (OrderId, BeerId, Brand, Name, Price, Quantity) Values (@OrderId,@BeerId,@Brand,@Name,@Price,@Quantity);";

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, connection);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderId", OrderId);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BeerId", BeerId);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Brand", Brand);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Name);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price", Price);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", Quantity);

        connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();
    }
}
}

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customers] 
(
    [CustomerId] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Username]   NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [Password]   NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [Name]       NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    [Email]      NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [Phone]      NUMERIC(18) NOT NULL,
    [Address1]   NVARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    [Address2]   NVARCHAR(25) NULL,
    [Address3]   NVARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    [Country]    NVARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([CustomerId] ASC)
);
```

This is for a college project. I hope I have given enough details.

Thanks
Anthony.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Very happy to see your professor teaching you to use parameterized queries. That all too often get overlooked and it critical to avoid sql injection. I would however caution you about using AddWithValue since you are not using stored procedures. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/ And I know this is not a real world application but I would be remiss if I didn't mention that passwords should never be stored as clear text, they should be salted and hashed.

Comment: For the question at hand, you need to run a query to retrieve the data you want displayed during page_load. Then you need to bind that data to your front end controls.

Comment: Hi Sean, This project is at it's baby stages, I will be added tweaks etc... to make it stronger.  My query is:  string getCustomerDetails = "SELECT Name, Email, Phone FROM Customers WHERE CustomerId = @id";

Comment: Hi Hardkoded. There is no error, it displays the page without the Name, Email and Passwords on the page. When I do a debug, it says the ID = "0" hence why it doesn;t have any of the customer data. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: You seem to be getting the id from the query string. What's the value of that query string?

Comment: Hi Frauke, The id from the query string should be the Customer ID from the Customer table.

Comment: "Should" is a dangerous word. What is the actual value of `id` after you try to parse the query string?

Comment: To be honest, I copied the parse code from another source of code, I have now removed the parse code. Essentially, what I am trying to do is, select certain columns from a table based on the Customer ID and display this information on the checkout.aspx page.

Comment: If the username logs in with a session id of "username" and the checkout has a session ID of "BeerCart" would this stop the information from displaying on the checkout.aspx page

Comment: In the AddCustomerDetails method you are not setting the Id param correctly.